# Slick2D - TextFields not working

Tags: slick2d

First, I have searched and found many problems and solutions for this and NONE of them worked.

In my game I have multiple states, one of them has 1 text field (which is working) and another has 2 text fields (where none of them is working) and I have no idea why it's not working.

1. I used the right code to initialise the game states like mentiond in many other answeres here
2. The font I use for all 3 text fields (and all other texts) is the same (same reference, no `font = new ...`)

If any of you have an idea what is going wrong here, please see https://github.com/MichaelJ2/big-buum-man/tree/master/source/bbm-map-editor
 (SaveScreen.java which is working and NewMapScreen.java which is not working)